# IndexError: list index out of range in game

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, oop, for-loop

Why do I get a `IndexError: list index out of range` error message in my pygame game?

I'm making a simple sake game, but when I add to the snakes' length each time it eats an apple I get an error.

This is the collision function

```
def collision(x1, y1, x2, y2, bsize):
    if x2 + bsize >= x1 >= x2:
        if y2 + bsize >= y1 >= y2:
            return True
    return False
```

Here is the eat the apple and die if collide with itself function.

```
    def eat(self):  # if it eats the apple
        for i in range(self.length):
            if collision(apple.x, apple.y, snake.x[i], snake.y[i], apple.width):  # entering the variables/coordinates
                self.length += 1
                apple.x_multiplier = random.randrange(row)  
                apple.y_multiplier = random.randrange(row)

                apple.x = (r_distance * apple.x_multiplier) + 1  # spawning the apple
                apple.y = (r_distance * apple.y_multiplier) + 1  # at a new coordinate

    def collide(self): # if colide with itself
        for i in range(2, self.length): 
            if collision(snake.x[0], snake.y[0], snake.x[i], snake.y[i], self.width):  # enetring the variables/coordinates
                self.alive = False  # killing the snake
```

Comment: updating self.length inside loop and using it in range also at same time is giving you this issue

Comment: @prashantrana how can I fix this, should I make a separate variable? Like ```for i in range(self.length + self.points)```and each time it eats an apple ```self.points += 1```

Comment: @prashantrana nope, that didn't work either

Comment: before for loop use, `value = self.length for i in range(value)`, keep rest thing sam

Comment: @prashantrana still the same error

Comment: this is coming in sanke.x[i] and snake.y[i], try to check it here, try to use a debugger in pycharm and see at what step you are facing this issue